# creating 100 objects with different name in a loop

Tags: c++, object, for-loop

How do I create a loop that will create 100 different object. Let's say I have class `myPage Page1`. 
I want to create 100 of those objects from `myPage` let's say Page1....Page100
also I need save the object name in a variable for example `char name[10]`

```
for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    // create object with different name of my class
    // char name = name of object//something like that
}
```

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have a look at `std::stringstream`. Sorry, misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted a name INSIDE your variable. Use an array!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6973/A-simple-string-generator-in-C

Answer (score 6):

> is it possible?

**No.** The name of variables in C++ is assigned at compile-time.

Just use a `std::vector<myPage>` (or `std::array<myPage, N>` if the size is determined at compile-time and shall not change) and access the objects positionally through their index.

Comment: +1 but to save name somewhere (and then search for name) I would use `std::map`.

Comment: @Adriano: That can be done too, but it seems to me what he is using to retrieve the variable is just the index. After all, what varies in `Page1`, `Page2`, ... `Page100` is just the suffix (index)

Comment: You're right, until I saw your answer I hadn't really clear what he wanted to achieve

Comment: Even if useless, I'm wondering if it's possible with Boost.Preprocessor.

Comment: @FredericS: I don't know and I don't want to know unless I'll have a good reason ;-)

Answer (score 2):

saying "The name of variables in C++ is assigned at compile-time.", Andy Prowl is right,
so you can't change the name of a variable during the execution.

But, if you want to do something impossible, there are others ways to fix your problem,
instead of get 100 var of the same type, you can instanciate a container filled with all your myPage instances, here is an ugly exemple :

```
std::map<std::string, myPage*> pages;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
   std::string name = "page";
   page += i;
   pages.insert (std::make_pair (name, new myPage ()));
}
```

and for access :

```
myPage* page = pages["page18"];
```

Comment: That's going to leak memory in 99% of cases. If you construct the objects at the time you put them into the map, without keeping a handle to them around, that means you want the map to have ownership of your objects. Use smart pointers, or just `emplace_back` the actual objects instead of pointers in the first place.

Comment: I didn't wanted to use smart pointers or something to show the "main" part of this code : name incrementation, that's why it's an 'ugly exemple'.
But I dind't realy understand what you mean by mem leak. Is this a problem that only the map have a pointer on the instances ? Because the std::map desctructor call the desctructors of all its components. so you can delete all your myPage instances when you don't need the myPage anymore. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. When a map holds objects, it will call the destructors of those objects. When a map holds raw pointers, only the memory taken by the pointers will be released, the objects pointed to live on. Nothing is `delete`d and no destructors are called.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in that way.
When you create objects you create an identifier (the name of your object in your source-code) and this one cannot be changed during runtime. You can create a class that has a `name`-member and assign this at construction-time.